# Regex contain one of specific numbers

Tags: php, regex, pcre

Let say I have a text like this

```
11/2/2010 10
22/3/2009 20
30/4/2003 30
14/5/1994 40
5/6/2000 50
```

And I only want to choose numbers after a string of a day in April or February (in this case it means '10' and '30'). I have tried:

```
\d+\/(2|4)\/\d+ (\d+)
```

but it captures also number '2' and '4' as group 1, then '10' and '30' as group 2 in result.

Please help!

P/S: I used pcre(php) as regex flavor

Comment: Do you mean you want to just get `10` and `30`? Try `preg_match('~\d+/[24]/\d+\s+\K\d+~', $s, $m)` (or if you process the whole text at once, use `preg_match_all`). Check [this demo](https://ideone.com/ypPO6j).

Comment: Please explain your problem. Right now, it is not clear.

Comment: If you only want to capture the last number, remove the first capturing group from your regex. Either by making the it non capturing: `\d+\/(?:2|4)\/\d+ (\d+)`, or maybe more *elegant* (?), change it for a character class matching 2 & 4: `\d+\/[24]\/\d+ (\d+)`

Comment: Both given answers are correct, however I wonder how this is a problem as you could just specify the index 2 instead of 1. Do you need it in index 0? If so, see the first comment. Please clarify.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes I just want to get `10` and `30` and `\d+\/(?:2|4)\/\d+ (\d+)` works perfectly for me

Comment: @ThanhToaiPHAN: Why doesn't work your regex as you could just pick index 2?!

Comment: @ThanhToaiPHAN: **Your** regex works perfectly for you. Just get the `$matches[2]`.

Comment: @hakre as I used regex101.com to pratice, I didn't know how to choose index 2, I'm pretty new to regex

Comment: You choose it like index 1 or 0. Normally as long as you have the match it's fine. Like in one of the previous comments, you access any matching group from the `$matches` array, e.g. `$matches[2]` (standard array access). And if you use regex101, you could link the regex that puzzles in the question as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this regex :

```
\d+\/(?:2|4)\/\d+ (\d+)
```

By adding `?:` you specifiy you don't want to capture the group `(2|4)`

Or here simply :

```
\d+\/[24]\/\d+ (\d+)
```

Answer (score 1):

If i understood you correctly:

```
^.*\/[24]\/.*?(?=\s)
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/1UxCSa/8)

Out of:

```
11/2/2010 10
22/3/2009 20
30/4/2003 30
14/5/1994 40
5/6/2000 50
```

This will match:

```
11/2/2010
30/4/2003
```